# Bundler config to either look for gems in custom path or download from custom source

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems, bundler

How do I configure bundler so that when I run `bundle install` it looks for gems under `/my/custom/path` first and if it doesn't find there then try to fetch them from a ruby gem remote repository hosted under `https://a.nice.host` and downloads those into `./local/relative/path` (relative to `cwd` for example).  I would like to avoid the bundler looking at default `gem` installation system path or rubygems.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for sourcing a gem from a local folder is:

```
gem 'some-gem-name', path: '/my/custom/path'
```

And the syntax for specifying a custom source is:

```
gem 'another-gem-name', source: 'https://a.nice.host'
```

And to install gems into a specific local folder, you can run:

```
bundle install --path ./local/relative/path
```

Now, that's **probably** all the tools you need, in truth... (And in fact, especially for that last requirement, you may instead wish to look into `rvm gemsets`, or using `bundle install --deployment`.)

But you did also ask about "looking in a local folder *first*, and only falling back to a remote source if it doesn't exist". That's quite an odd requirement (usually you'd only want to explicitly **opt-in** to fetching gems from a local path?!), but to answer this question as you've asked it...

A `Gemfile` is literally just ruby code! So you can define this logic using... You guessed it, ruby! For example:

```
if File.exists?('/my/custom/path')
  gem 'some-gem-name', path: '/my/custom/path'
else
  gem 'some-gem-name', source: 'https://a.nice.host'
end
```

If this (unusual) pattern needs to be repeated in multiple places, you could wrap it into some helper method.

For more information on the configuration options of `bundler`, please see [the documentation](https://bundler.io/bundle_install.html).